# Anyone knows why my scrollview on Android Studio doesn't work?

Tags: android-studio, scroll, scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="900dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/bettermainactivity2">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="219dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
        android:text=" The Archer Queen"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="videoplay"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:text="PLAY"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="417dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="The Archer Queen card is unlocked upon reaching King Level 14. She is a single-target ranged troop who targets both Ground and Air units with moderately high damage per second and hitpoints. Being a Champion card, she will stay out of the player's card cycle, and only return once she is destroyed. The Archer Queen's ability makes her invisible (Similar to the Royal Ghost) and increases her attack speed significantly for a short time."/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="244dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
        android:text="Elixir Cost:   5\nAbility Cost:    1\nRarity:  Champion\nType:    Troop\nRelease Date: 27/08/2021"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="109dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/archerqueen" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/homebutt" />


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="185dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to be able to scroll on my page downwards, so added scrollview on top of all my other code. I thought that this was the correct decision, but I guess not. I don't know why but when I open an emulator it doesn't let me scroll. Does anyone know if I have done something wrong? Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ScrollView` under any layout to work responsively. And I changed `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView` if you want you can use `ScrollView`

Your new code is below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="219dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
            android:text=" The Archer Queen"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="videoplay"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
            android:text="PLAY"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="417dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="The Archer Queen card is unlocked upon reaching King Level 14. She is a single-target ranged troop who targets both Ground and Air units with moderately high damage per second and hitpoints. Being a Champion card, she will stay out of the player's card cycle, and only return once she is destroyed. The Archer Queen's ability makes her invisible (Similar to the Royal Ghost) and increases her attack speed significantly for a short time."/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="244dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/clashfont"
            android:text="Elixir Cost:   5\nAbility Cost:    1\nRarity:  Champion\nType:    Troop\nRelease Date: 27/08/2021"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="109dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/archerqueen" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:src="@drawable/archerqueen" />


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If problem is the same, let me know

Comment: I used the code that you provided but it didn't work. Do you have maybe any other proposals?

Comment: @Xontros4u can I see how your layout looks like and what problem in your layout. Mention problem image with your question.